# How to ensure that dropdown field is a mandatory input field for submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**Task:**

To create a form  where there is a dropdown list that is a mandatory field for user to select before submission.

**What has been done**

Have created a dropdown list  with the following list: Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Others. Upon, selecting "Others", there are 3 additional mandatory fields that need to be answered before submission. In conclusion, all fields are mandatory.

What I have managed to do was to make the additional field mandatory.

**Issue:**
I have managed to make the additional fields (additional fields will only display when user select "Others") mandatory, but I can't seem to make the dropdown list a mandatory field. Hence, when a user select "Name A" from the dropdown list, it will still prompt for a field input in the additional fields, when it is displayed that the user has selected "Name A" option.

-Name A, Name B and Name C already has name information stored and it will only reflect the names when user select either of the 3 options.

Hence, how am I able to make the dropdown list part of a mandatory field? Thus, the mandatory field prompt will only appear when the user has yet to select any options, but wouldn't show when the user has made a selection on any of the options?

**Code:**

```js
<!-- Code that display fields when option has been selected: -->
<script>
function val(x) {
    document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = x == "Others" ? "block" : "none";   
    document.getElementById("Name1").style.display = x == "Name 1" ? "block" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById("Name2").style.display = x == "Name 2" ? "block" : "none"; 
    document.getElementById("Name3").style.display = x == "Name 3" ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Dropdown code -->
<p>

<select name ="Details" id="Details" class="defaultValue required" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
<option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Name..</option>
<option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
<option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
<option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
<option value = "Others"> Others</option>
</select>
</p>

<!-- Code for additional fields when user select "Others": -->

<div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">
<p>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name" title="Name" class="defaultValue required" tabindex="7" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="RegistrationNum" id="RegistrationNum" value="Registration Num" title="Registration Num" class="leftCol defaultValue required validateInput formatNumber" tabindex="8" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" value="Address" title="Address" class="defaultValue required signupinput_txt" tabindex="9" />
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use html5 validation if your targeted browsers supports it.

```
<select required>
<option value="">empty select value</option>
<option value="blabla">blabla</option>
</select>
```

you can check browser support here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=validation

Comment: I have initially added `required` within the class and have also added required in select, I am not able to get it

Comment: try: http://jsfiddle.net/d81d52dy/. i tried it on chrome and firefox and it works. on safari it doesn't. check browser support in the link i posted.

Answer (score 0):

for example make a button and check on click.

```js
<script>
    function formSubmit(){
         if(document.getElementById('Details').value == 0){
            alert('Select Any One'); 
            document.getElementById('Details').focus();      
         }
         else if(document.getElementById('Details').value== 'Others' && document.getElementById('othersTxt').value==''){
            alert('fill the text box'); 
         }
         else {
            document.getElementById('dropdownForm').submit();
         }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form id="dropdownForm">
    <select name ="Details" id="Details" class="defaultValue required" onchange = "return val(this.value);">
    <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Name..</option>
    <option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
    <option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
    <option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
    <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="othersTxt">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="formSubmit();">
</form>
```

Comment: I already have a button that does the check, hence when the form is not completed, it will prompt, thats how i am getting the prompt. Secondly, I have added the class ="default value required". furthermore, There is already text to prompt for the input of field, it is in another function. How is it possible to just make the dropdown field a mandatory field, I do not need to assign separate text or submit button to it

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Form validations [Guide](http://www.javascript-coder.com/form-validation/jquery-form-validation-guide.phtml)

Answer (score 0):

check to see if that option is selected, and then put more conditions.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        if($("select[name='Details']").selectedIndex == 4)
        {
            //other conditions
            alert('Last Element is selected, more info are required');
        }
    </script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($("select[name='Details']").text == 'Others')
    {
        //some code
        alert('more info');
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: Maybe you prefer this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkForm() {
         if((document.getElementById("Details")).selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            alert('This field is required');
            return false;
        } 
        if((document.getElementById("Details")).selectedIndex == 4)
        {
            //other conditions
             if((document.getElementById("Name")).value == "Name"){
             alert('Last Element is selected, more info are required');
             return false;
             }
         }
        return true       
}
</script>


<form onsubmit="return checkForm()" method="post" action="#"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name ="Details" id="Details" class="defaultValue required">
<option value ="0"> Select Name..</option>
<option value ="Name 1"> Name1</option>
<option value ="Name 2"> Name2</option>
<option value ="Name 3"> Name3</option>
<option value = "Others"> Others</option>
</select>

<!-- Code for additional fields when user select "Others": -->

<div id = "extradiv">
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name" title="Name" class="defaultValue required" tabindex="7" />
</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: what conditions are you referring about

Comment: Your code, doesnt seem to be checking if the dropdodwn has been selected. It is only adding a method of what will the selection do when it is being selected by the user.  I have done that in my code, refer to my above code within the <script></script>

Comment: @EEE Your question: "selecting "Others", there are 3 additional mandatory fields that need to be answered before submission.". If user select that option, you can put more conditions, for other fields.